# What is "DSC Update" for a monitor?

Tags: display, automatic-update, auto-updates

I am using Samsung Odyssey LC27G7xT connected to a Linux machine via HDMI and to a Mac via DisplayPort.

Very occasionally, the monitor would show a black screen with the following progress bar in the right bottom corner:

[image]

It would run for a couple of minutes maybe, then the monitor would continue to work as normal.

What is it?

I would presume it was an automatic software update, but I would be very surprised to learn it is possible via either HDMI or DisplayPort. I checked the monitor settings and the closest thing was "Software Update" but that is done manually by using a flash drive.

Comment: DSC [Display Stream Compression] is a video compression codec. Unless you have very new hardware [I think the 2020 iMac is the earliest Mac], I doubt you have support for it, so perhaps it's just the display 'hunting' for compatibility info. See https://www.cablematters.com/blog/DisplayPort/what-is-display-stream-compression

Comment: @Tetsujin The mac is Mac Mini M1, 2020.

Comment: Do you have a DisplayPort 1.4 cable? [& it would need HDMI 2.1 for the other] See https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/m1-mac-mini-hdmi-2-1-port-dp-1-4-dsc-1-2.2276840/

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know how to check which version the DP cable is. The cable itself does not say. Checked System Report in the mac but no DP version either. Are you saying the "DSC Update" thing will happen with one DP cable version but not with another?